# Firebase loading data for android quiz app

Tags: android, firebase, loading

Im creating a quiz app for android and I'm using Firebase to store my data.When the app starts all the questions are loaded in the onCreate() method but the problem is that my app start before the loading is completed and it crashes .What i want to do is to have a loading screen ,and the questions don't start until the loading is completed .Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You forgot to attach the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without seeing that, it'll be difficult to help.

Comment: There is no problem in the code, what I need is to make a loading screen in the begining that gonna end when all questions are loaded from firebase but I dont have any idea about how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

As you are loading huge data from firebase ,its better to fetch it in seperate thread and update your  main activity after it's fetched completely.
For this purpose you can use ASYNC TASK.

```
class fetchdata extends AsyncTask 
{
 @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // Runs on the UI thread before doInBackground()
    }

@Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
        // Fetch data here
        Log.d(TAG, "MyAsyncTask@doInBackground from another thread");

        return new Object();
    }
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Result result) {
        // Runs on the UI thread after doInBackground()
//update main activity here
    }
}
```

After creating async task class , you have to call it in main class by:

```
fetchdata obj = new fetchdata();
obj.execute();//this will execute async task seperatly.
```

you can also use progress dialog for the time data is fetching in async task.